# How can a console command executed from a program create a graphical dialog to respond to an input prompt?

Tags: shell, command-line, prompt, freepascal, lazarus

How can a Lazarus/FPC program that is executing a command via `TProcess` detect an input prompt and create a graphical dialog for the input?

e.g. say I execute an `ssh` command via `TProcess` which requires a password to be input - how could it detect it, prompt for it with a graphical dialog and pass it on for the command to continue?

Comment: Very maybe, you might be able to detect that a program needs input. (if you can somehow detect the program blocks on the input stdhandle). But _what_ it wants inputed is guesswork based on parsing output. Hardly a general case for that.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Does the TProcess or some other package have the ability to input keystrokes back into the program, as though it is operating a console? Does TProcess itself have the ability, or does it simply sends the text without any possibility of feed back, unless the process itself has the ability to do that outside of TProcess's control?

Comment: TProcess can send binary data on the std input of the other program. If and how the other program processes that data, depends on the other program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have at least two choices:

1. For "text graphics" (eg: text boxes) use whiptail or dialog and catch their output, it'll contain pure text password entered by user, example for dialog: `dialog --passwordbox "Please enter password:" 10 40`
2. For X-Window graphical screen you can use zenity and grab the output, it'll contain pure text password, example: `zenity --password --title "Security question: "`